# Postgres UPSERT syntax confusion

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have a table with 2 columns:
channels TEXT
rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

I included an index on channels 
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX channels_index on mytable (lower(channels))

so that VisitToronto will be a conflict with visittoronto

All works well and the conflict fires. 
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "channels_index"
DETAIL:  Key (lower(words))=(hello world) already exists.

I can not figure out the syntax to trap this conflict.  ON CONFLICT channels doesn't work  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT channels_index doesn't work

The closest I've got is: 
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Any direction would be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index expression, i.e. `lower(channels)`:

```
insert into my_table (channels) values
('VisitToronto');

insert into my_table (channels) 
values ('visittoronto')
on conflict (lower(channels)) do 
update set channels = excluded.channels;

select *
from my_table;

 id |   channels   
----+--------------
  1 | visittoronto
(1 row)
```

You are not able to use a constraint because the index is on an expression. In the case Postgres cannot create a constraint:

```
alter table my_table add constraint channels_unique unique using index channels_index;

ERROR:  index "channels_index" contains expressions
LINE 1: alter table my_table add constraint channels_unique unique u...
                                 ^
DETAIL:  Cannot create a primary key or unique constraint using such an index.
```

Comment: Brilliant thank-you.  I also now understand what the Docs a little better too.  Is there a way of returning channels_rowid without doing the update?  If not that's o'kay, I don't really care which version is in the database, mostly just educating myself.  I'm using 'returning channels_rowid' after the update statement which gets returned for both the insert and the update but if I "DO NOTHING" it doesn't return, If I use a SELECT I get an error

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot return anything from `do nothing` as no row was affected. You would need a function to accomplish this.